# "Connection to localhost closed by remote host." when rsyncing over ssh

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm trying to set up an automatic rsync backup (using cron) over an ssh tunnel but am getting an error "Connection to localhost closed by remote host.".  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  I've searched for help and tried many solutions such as adding ALL:ALL to /etc/hosts.allow, check for #MaxStartups 10:30:60 in sshd_config, setting UsePrivilegeSeparation no in sshd_config, creating /var/empty/sshd but none have fixed the problem.

I have autossh running to make sure the tunnel is always there:

```
autossh -M 25 -t -L 2222:destination.address.edu:22 pbeyersdorf@intermediate.address.edu -N -f
```

This seems to be running fine, and I've been able to use the tunnel for various rsync tasks, and in fact the first time I ran the following rsync task via cron it succeeded:

```
rsync -av --delete-after /tank/Documents/ peteman@10.0.1.5://Volumes/TowerBackup/tank/Documents/
```

with the status of each file and the output

```
sent 7331634 bytes  received 88210 bytes  40215.96 bytes/sec
total size is 131944157313  speedup is 17782.61
```

Ever since that first success, every attempt gives me the following output

```
building file list ... Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

An rsync operation of a smaller subdirectory works as expected.  I'd appreciate any ideas on what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issues is related to autossh.  If I create my tunnel via ssh instead of autossh it works fine.  I suspect I could tweak the environment variables that affect the autossh configuration, but for my purposes I've solved the problem by wrapping the rsycn command in a script that first opens a tunnel via ssh, executes the backup then kills the ssh tunnel, thereby eliminating the need for the always open tunnel created by autossh:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Start SSH tunnel
ssh -t -L 2222:destination.address.edu:22 pbeyersdorf@intermediate.address.edu -N -f
#execute backup commands
rsync -a /tank/Documents/ peteman@localhost://Volumes/TowerBackup/tank/Documents/ -e "ssh -p 2222"
#Kill SSH tunnel
pkill -f "ssh.*destination.address"
```